# Can I condense multiple grid-column declarations into one?

Tags: css, css-grid

```
.col1 {
    grid-column: 1;
}
.col2 {
    grid-column: 2;
}
.col3 {
    grid-column: 3;
}
```

Is there a way I can condense this down to one part, I.E

```
.col[0-9]{
    grid-column: [0-9];
}
```

Comment: No, Even SASS/LESS will just make the code easier to write, the compiled CSS will still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Not using regular CSS, but with [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for) you could use a `@for` loop like this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 9 {
  .col#{$i} {
    grid-column: #{$i};
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that Sass will still compile to the same, more verbose CSS output (in case someone reading doesn't understand exactly how Sass works).